# How to prove the following limit is the same for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, probability-theory

I have a claim in Durrett saying: Let $\mu_n$ be a measure s.t. it has a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $n$, then $\mu_n((-\infty,x])\rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$.

So may I know how to find the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2n}}dx$ ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\int_{-\infty}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2n}}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{x}{\sqrt n}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi }}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx.$$
Now note that $\frac{x}{\sqrt n}\to 0$ for all $x$ and apply DCT.